# How to solve an ODE with matlab for different parameter values?

Tags: matlab, ode

I would like to solve the simple 1d ode and get the different solution vectors as long as the parameter p varies on a certain range

dx/dt=25.7+x*(0.00038*x-0.00000014*x^2)-x*(0.162+0.00000006*x^2)-p*x

Here is my code

```
function dxdt = lv(t,x,p)

dxdt = 25.7+x*(0.00038*x-0.00000014*x^2)-x*(0.162+0.00000006*x^2)-p*x;
end
```

and

```
clear all

% Write here the initial conditions
xstart = 1200.0;

tspan = 0:1000;

%parameters
% s = 25.7;
% a = 0.00038;
% b = -0.00000014;
% c = 0.162;
% d = 0.00000006;
%p = 0.01;

p = 0:0.001:0.1;
x_end=zeros(length(tspan),length(p));

for ii = 1:length(p)
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x)lv(t,x,p(ii)),tspan,xstart);
end
```

I would like to collect the solution vectors obtained for any value of p.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help or suggestion

Comment: So you will need to add `x_end(:,ii)=x` to your loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it seems working and that's exactly what I needed. I think I did some mistakes in populating the x_end matrix before